# Matches IP address (content_scripts)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I want next matches:

```js
"content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["*://1.1.1.*/*"],
          "run_at": "document_end",
          "all_frames": true,
          "js": ["/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "/js/contentScript.js"]
        }
    ],
```

but error:
Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Invalid host wildcard.

How can I use 1.1.1.* ?

Comment: Try with [`include_globs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#matchAndGlob).

Comment: Wow! Thank you! :) Work this: 
"matches": ["*://*/*"],
"include_globs": ["*1.1.1.*/*"],